# gem5 : Consecutive memory access for data in L1/L2 cache

Tags: gem5

I am using SE mode , x86  in gem5 and trying to find out the following data for any executable code OR benchmarks.

1. Consecutive data memory access for data in L1/L2 ? 
   For example , instruction fetched  is to add two numbers which reside in same data cache. Can we identify by some tracing methods that how many like these consecutive data fetches are done from L1/L2 to CPU ?

   What i have tried : --debug-flags=Cache , But not able to extract the desired data. 
   Also not able to modify code for Memtrace - Not sure what to modify in which files ?
2. Quantitatively get L1/L2/L3 latencies. Is is possible to get this ?

What i have tried : Tried pointer-chasing method do disable prefetching. The expected output should be at some size of the array the number of misses in caches will trigger a jump. You can count then the number of misses as accesses made to the cache. But i see no jump in size of array VS # of misses. The graph is linear.

Thanks & Regards,
Ayan

Comment: Could you rephrase your first question? Also, when you ask questions you should inform the commit hash of the gem5 version you are using, and the command that you used to run gem5. Anyway, the latencies are given by you, in the config file that you used (if you haven't used any, check configs/common/Caches.py for the default values). Also, you can simply not add any prefetcher in your configs. If you want the average miss latency, this is given in the stats.txt (for example, system.l2.overall_avg_miss_latency::total). Access/hit latency can be added similarly to mem/cache/base.cc::regStats().

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your reply. I will  try to explain (1) in details 

For the gem5 commit/version , i am not sure how to check since it was downloaded few months back. 


Target is to find consecutive address requests from memory for data transport/fetch to the CPU. For example , instruction is to add two numbers residing at data-memory locations "FD00 0000" and "FD00 FFFF" in the same L1. How is it possible to find this out from any gem5 output ? Will Commmonitor/MemtraceProbe help in this case ?

Comment: The command used is :


time ./build/X86/gem5.opt --debug-flags=CommMonitor --debug-file=trace.comm  -d ./m5_out_sparse  ./configs/example/se.py -c $BENCHMARK  -I 100000000 --cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU --caches --l2cache --l3cache --l1d_size=32kB --l1i_size=32kB --l2_size=1MB --l1d_assoc=2 --l1i_assoc=2 --l2_assoc=1 --l3_size=4MB --cacheline_size=64

I have tried to add L3 level also

Comment: It is still an explanation of what you want, not a concise question, so I am having trouble to understand, so I will answer "How do I know if data sent to CPU was a hit in the LX cache?". IDK any existing methods to determine from which cache data comes, nor how to extract hit/miss information from a packet, but you can use name() within the cache that had a hit to get its unique name, and then store this information in the packet that will be returned as a response (i.e., create such variable in Packet, and insert it in handleTimingReqHit()).